# In ASIHttpRequest CFReadStreamOpen((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream])) doesn't send data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

in ASIHTTPRequest class

I debug  - (void)main  method of the NSOperation with wireshark . I want to find which method  send data.

But i debug to the end of startRequest in main method  of NSOperation. I can't  grab  any  data.

Because the read stream opens a socket connection with the server specified by the myUrl parameter when the CFHTTP request was created, some amount of time must be allowed to pass before the stream is considered to be open. Opening the read stream also causes the request to be serialized and sent.

base the above document of apple  about "Communicating with HTTP Servers"

the most chance to send data is  the below code .But it don't. I can't find something  in wireShark.

```
CFStreamClientContext ctxt = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
if (CFReadStreamSetClient((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream], kNetworkEvents, ReadStreamClientCallBack, &ctxt)) {
    if (CFReadStreamOpen((CFReadStreamRef)[self readStream])) {
        streamSuccessfullyOpened = YES;
    }
}
```

where  send  data ????  like socket send or sendto function.

Answer (score 0):

ASIHTTPRequest is built on top of CFNetwork's HTTP abstraction (see `CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest` and so on), so it never directly calls 'send' on a socket.

ASIHTTPRequest "sends" data by telling CFHTTP to send it - eg. `CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue`.